# New reputation factor: No questions penalty

Tags: discussion, reputation

Our site suffers from too many bad questions. We are the [second worst site in the entire network](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) regarding answer rate. Bad questions do not get answers and they drive away the most important community members: *experts*.
We need more good questions. Good questions are asked by people who know what they do, usually people with high reputation.

To solve this problem I asked the SE team for a minor change on our site. And they said **yes!**

I am very proud to announce this change today: From now on we are a test site for a new feature called **No questions penalty**.

How it works: Each week you don’t ask a question you will lose 1% (one percent) of your reputation. Closed questions or questions with a negative vote count will not be taken into account, so your question has to be [good](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

After six months the effects will be evaluated and – if they are positive – rolled out to the entire network.

Comment: -1: I think this is gonna compound the problem of many unanswered questions, not improve it. It will also lead to rep-conscious users coming up with (primarily) bogus questions, or "do my work for me question". Questions need to arise from a need or a lack of understanding, so for users who aren't covering any new ground in their coding this requirement will  be detrimental.

Comment: [tag:april-first]

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of feature that should have been discussed with the community first.  I am **vehemently** opposed to such a feature.

We should be encouraging good questions and incentivizing experts to answer questions.  Not, and I repeat ***not***, penalizing those who don't ask questions.

I rarely ask questions here because I have limited time to devote to the site, spend most of my time answering questions for others and because I know enough about WP that asking a question I already know the answer to seems hollow.  This feature would rob me of roughly 130 points per week if I continue to let those who really have questions ask the questions.

Had this feature been put to a vote, I would have voted no and campaigned as hard as possible against it.

-1

Comment: Just realized this question was posted on April Fools Day ... unfortunately, when I read it it was 4am and I was getting ready to run a half marathon, so the fact that it was a joke didn't quite compute :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with with @EAMann,

This kind of feature should be discussed between us (the community) before, and I'm strongly opposed to the feature as well.

I'm opposed because i feel that we should care about members of the community and not **FORCE** users to ask question. (and if you think bad question drive experts away, try forcing them to do something and see what happens). we should help our members to ask better questions and care more about the members who ask the questions then so called "Experts" that leave the site if the question are bad.

personally I'm a member here for about 14 months and in all that time I've asked 3 questions, and answered 1176, obviously i rather spend  my time answering questions then asking a question which i either know the answer or don't even care. And only ask questions when i really have a question.

Also i strongly feel that moves like this (initiating a new feature) should be community approved and not a single member decision.

-1

Answer (score 0):

Wow guys...

```
88      dP"Yb   88     
88     dP   Yb  88     
88     Yb   dP  88  
88ood8  YbodP   88ood8
```

You got em @toscho ;)

Where did clippy go, I thought that was also a new feature.

Comment: Next year I’ll announce a hard reset for all rep. Stay tuned.